# How to use Dapper asynchronously with multiple stored procedure calls?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, stored-procedures, dapper

I'm using the Dapper ORM in an ASP.Net Core 2.1 CRUD application, with a SQL Server database. For a new form I'm developing, I want to retrieve all reference data (to populate `SELECT` field options) in one go when the screen is invoked. This involves a series of stored procedure calls, which I want to do asynchronously for best performance.

[This Dapper tutorial](http://dapper-tutorial.net/async#querymultipleasync) suggests I should look at using `QueryMultipleAsync`, but I can't find an example of its use with stored procedures, only hard-coded SQL statements.

My C# code currently looks like this:

```
public async Task<ContactReferenceData> Get()
{
    ContactReferenceData refData = new ContactReferenceData();

    try
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = _connection)
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            var countryData = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Country>(sql: "usp_GetCountries", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            refData.CountryDetails = countryData.AsList();
            var companyData = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Company>(sql: "usp_GetCompanies", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            refData.CompanyDetails = companyData.AsList();
            var groupData = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Group>(sql: "usp_GetGroups", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            refData.GroupDetails = groupData.AsList();
            var groupPositionData = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<GroupPosition>(sql: "usp_GetGroupPositions", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            refData.GroupPositionDetails = groupPositionData.AsList();
        }

        return refData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

This works OK in my test environment, but I'm not sure it's the correct way to execute async queries. In particular, I have the following concerns:

1. is it robust enough to be trusted in live operation?
2. in its current form, is it maximising the benefits (if any) of asynchronous operation, or should I be using `QueryMultipleAsync` to properly achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
public async Task<ContactReferenceData> Get()
{
   var sql = "EXEC usp_GetCountries; EXEC usp_GetCompanies; EXEC usp_GetGroups; EXEC usp_GetGroupPositions";
    ContactReferenceData refData = new ContactReferenceData();

    try
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = _connection)
        {
            using (var multi = connection.QueryMultipleAsync(sql: sql, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure ).Result)
    {
        refData.CountryDetails = multi.Read<countryDetails>().ToList();
        refData.CompanyDetails = multi.Read<CompanyDetails>().ToList();
        refData.GroupData = multi.Read<Groups>().ToList();
        refData.GroupPositionsData= multi.Read<GroupPositions>().ToList();
    }
        }

        return refData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that, but it errored as it did not recognise "countryDetails" in "Read<countryDetails>", presumably as that is a C# construct, whereas it expects a SQL entity there, such as a tablename. I could look at fixing that, but I feel I would lose the separation of logic between the C# code and the stored procedures.